# How to indicate the source of the link is your website?

Tags: seo, links, backlinks

Let's say you own website A which includes a link to website B.

How can you tag your links on A so that when a user clicks on them, the owner of B, by looking at his/her Google analytic data, can count how many links have come from A? Is this already done automatically, or can you add something to the link to hightlight this?

**Update:**

I tried [google url builder](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/campaign-url-builder/) and it seems to work.

```
websiteB.com?utm_source=websiteA&utm_medium=posts&utm_campaign=test
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<a href="https://siteb.com?ref=sitea">Click here for site B</a>
```

Something like that will do it

Comment: I wasn't able to see any result from sitea in Google analytics, but looks like using utm tags work.